# if statement "not a statement"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Example code:

```
public class SalCal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=0;
        if (a > 1)
            String string = "fds";//hint:not a statement
    }
}
```

Intellij IDEA hints at `String string = "fds";`

> not a statement

But if I add braces on the either hand of  `String string = "fds";` , it will not hint like before anymore. Why?

Comment: The `{...}` generate context around the statement, as it stands `String string = "fds";` means nothing, as the variable can't be used and just kind of blinks in and out of existance

Comment: Does that code make any sense ? control will never go inside if

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intellij IDEA says that because it is not a statement.  It is a declaration<sup>1</sup>.

When you add the braces, you are turning it into a block statement ... which is a statement.

But here's the rub.  If this code was legal it would be useless.

```
  if (a> 1)
        String string = "fds";
```

Why?  Because the scope of the declaration has to end when the `if` statement ends.  You would be declaring a variable that *cannot* be used.

---

Here are a couple of alternatives:

1) This version declares the variable in the if-block

```
  if (a> 1) {
        String string = "fds";
        // you can use 'string' here
  }
  // ... but not here, because it is now out-of-scope.
```

2) This version declares and initializes the variable before the if statement and assigns a new value to it in the if:

```
  String string = "asdf";
  if (a> 1) {
        string = "qwerty";  // assignment, not declaration
  }
  // OK to use 'string' here.
```

---

@Maroun's answer gives the technical reason why what you have written is not valid Java code.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, the Intellij IDEA compiler is being "loose with the truth".  In fact, the JLS calls that a "local variable declaration statement".  So it is technically a "statement" ... but it is special kind that cannot be used in all contexts that an ordinary one can be used.</sup>

Comment: You are right. But I am afraid that I don't agree with your view "it's not a statement, It is a declaration.", due to the fact that declaration statements are also one of statements according to[JAVA tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

Comment: It is not my point of view.  I am explaining the Intellij IDEA compiler's "point of view".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the [JLS - 6.1. Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1):

> A local variable, one of the following:
>
> - A local variable declared in a block ([§14.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4))
> - A local variable declared in a for statement ([§14.14](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14))

Your case is none of the above, so you're getting:

```
error: variable declaration not allowed here
```

There are many solutions for this:

- Declare `string` in an outer scope
- Add parenthesis to the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The line `String string = "fds";` is a *declaration* with an initializer, not a statement (such as a method call or an assignment to an existing variable). When you use braces, you're introducing a new block scope in which it can make sense to declare block-local variables, but in a bare "then", it's completely useless to declare a variable.

Answer (score 0):

1.)First

String string = "asdf";

//if you don't have a curly braces here you've just like

//all of those things that is inside the if will follow the condition

if (a> 1)

//statement

2.)Second

//you use those {} just to block your statements
String string = "asdf";

if(a>1){// and this is always a statement;

//statement string

}